# Euler-Lagrange equations from variational principle in 2D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, euler-lagrange-equation

I want to **derive the Euler-Lagrange equations (ELE)** from an action $$S=\int\int\mathcal{L}(x, y, z, \partial_y x, \partial_zx) dydz$$ where $x$ **depends on two variables** $x=x(y,z)$, imposing $\delta S=0$, but I find some extra terms that I don't think should be there.
I proceeded as follows:
$$0=\delta S=\delta\left(\int\int\mathcal{L}dydz \right)=\int\int\delta(\mathcal{L})dydz=\int\int\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x}\delta x+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial y}\delta y+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial z}\delta z+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_yx}\delta \partial_yx+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_zx}\delta \partial_zx\right)dydz=$$
$$=\int\int\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\partial_y \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_yx}-\partial_z \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_zx}\right)\delta xdydz+\text{boundary conditions}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\partial_y \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_yx}+\partial_z \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_zx}$$
if the boundary conditions are met.
Is this formula the correct ELE in 2D? **How should I treat** the $\partial y / \partial x$, $\partial z / \partial x$?

Does this change **if the extrema of the integrals are functions of the variables**? For example, if my action is $$S=\int_0^1 dz\int_{\hat{y}(z)}^1dy\mathcal{L}(x, y, z, \partial_y x, \partial_zx)$$

Comment: You are making a small change in the function $x$. That will also mean small changes in its derivatives $\partial_{y}x$ and $\partial_{z}x$. But the other two terms are extraneous—there is no translation $(\delta y,\delta z)$ involved.

Comment: @Ali So I should *not* consider the change of $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $y$ and $z$, even if there is an explicit dependence on these variables?